# Entity Framework Core - DataReader must be closed error when query two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an issue of using Entity Framework Core with MYSQL in my Asp.net Core 3.1 project. I got an error

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

when querying two tables at the same time and then joining them. The detailed implementation is as follows - any suggestion is appreciated.

I try to avoid using `ToList()` after query in each table, thereby avoiding too much in memory operations.

In my project, I created an `UnitOfWork` with the following code.

```
public class UnitOfWork<T> : IUnitOfWork<T> where T : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ThreadLocal<T> _localContext;
    public T DbContext => _localContext.Value;

    public UnitOfWork(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DbContextOptions dbContextOptions)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<UnitOfWork<T>>();
        _localContext = new ThreadLocal<T>(() => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), dbContextOptions));
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return 0
    }

    void IUnitOfWork<T>.RegisterDeleted<TAggregateRoot>(TAggregateRoot entity)
    {
    }

    void IUnitOfWork<T>.RegisterModified<TAggregateRoot>(TAggregateRoot entity)
    {
    }

    void IUnitOfWork<T>.RegisterNew<TAggregateRoot>(TAggregateRoot entity)
    {
    }
}
```

After that I inject the `IUnitOfWork<>` as a singleton as

```
 builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<>)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>)).SingleInstance();
```

For each repository of entity that is going to be saved to database, `IUnitOfWork<T>` is injected through its constructor.

For example, I have table `A` and table `B` in database, and I have `EntityA` and `EntityB` as models that corresponding to these two tales. For each of them, I have `RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB`. In the example, `EntityAs` is `DbSet<EntityA> EntityAs` in `DbContext`.

```
public class RepositoryA: IRepository
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public RepositoryA(IUnitOfWork<EntityA> unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork
    }

    public IEnumerable<EntityA> List()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.DbContext.EntityAs;
    }
}
```

Now, When I try to use `RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB` together in a service class as

```
public class Service
{
    public Service(RepositoryA repoA, RepositoryB repoB)
    {
        let entityAs = repoA.List();
        let entityBs = repoB.List();

        let result = from entityA in entityAs
                     join entityB in eneityBs
                     on entityA.BId equals entityB.Id
                     where entityA.Id == 1
                     select entityB;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is because you create dbcontext in ThreadLocal and declare your UnitOfWork as singleton, try to define both of them as Transient and your problem should be solved

Comment: Yes, you are right, changing the UnitOfWork scope solves the problem. Thank you. If you can move your answer to a reply, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change

`builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<>)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>)).SingleInstance();`

to

`builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<>)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>)).InstancePerDependency();`

solved the problem